# Product image and audio are not storing in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, backend

I'm working on ecommerce project and products are successfully created. product include name, description, price, image, and audio file. But in databse it is only storing the name, price, and image.I'm using multer as a Middleware to store my product in binary form but didn't workut and didn't give any error.

e.g.

_id":{"$oid":"6551d8e1323429331428c2ee"
"name":"Rap",
"description":"Mumble Rap",
"price":"250$",
"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"

```
`const Product = require('../models/productModel');

// Controller for getting a list of products
const getProducts = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const products = await Product.find();
    res.json(products);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error fetching products' });
  }
};

const createProduct = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name, description, price } = req.body;
    const productImage = req.files['productImage'][0].buffer; 
    const productAudio = req.files['productAudio'][0].buffer;

    console.log('Received POST request to create a product');
    console.log('Product Name:', name);
    console.log('Product Description:', description);
    console.log('Product Price:', price);
    console.log('Product Image:', productImage);
    console.log('Product Audio:', productAudio);

    const newProduct = new Product({
      name,
      description,
      price,
      image: productImage,
      audio: productAudio,
    });

    const savedProduct = await newProduct.save();
    console.log('Product saved:', savedProduct);

    res.status(201).json(savedProduct);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error creating the product' });
  }
};

module.exports = {
  getProducts,
  createProduct,
};

`const multer = require('multer');

//Define storage options for multer
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'uploads/'); 
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
  },
});

// Create an instance of multer with the defined storage options
const upload = multer({ storage });

// Handle file upload
const uploadFile = (req, res) => {
  // Process the uploaded file (e.g., save it, update the product record with the file path)
  res.json({ message: 'File uploaded successfully' });
};

module.exports = { uploadFile };
`
```

Answer (score 0):

check this artical see if it helps
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/gridfs/